# Why can't we update the deactivated process builder instead of creating its version?

Tags: process-builder

Every time I want to make any change in the process builder, I need to create version of it. Why cant we update the deactivated version instead of creating new one.

Comment: The general, non-satisfying answer is "because that's how Salesforce decided to design that feature". I suspect that we'd need to get some input from someone on Salesforce's product team to get any answer beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my guess:

Some Process Builder Flows can have time based actions in the queue so the version that started them needs to still exist unchanged.

Same for Lightning Flows that can be paused. Same Flow Interview infrastructure behind it as for Process Builder Flows.

It'd be too difficult to evaluate which flow is safe to change so you can't change any.